# Best Practice Spring 4 Controller MVC - Service releation

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, service, controllers

I have a question which i couldn't find on the net. So what is actually the best practice to use Controllers in SPRING 4 MVC? 
Is it better to use for each service one controller, which produce a lot of controllers if you have a lot of services. In my case i would need about 12 controllers?

I have also only some services which only call simple dao methods like create/getAll and so on. And other services that generate specific data out of there input.

So what would you recommend to handle a best practice?

best regards
patrick

Comment: Why would you create one controller per service? Controllers are used to connect the model layer and the presentation layer, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Use a controller per functionnality (ie: customer management, auth, registration, ...).

In your controller, process only the HTTP request and then call your services or directly your dao (if it is a basic processing like CRUD operations)

Comment: That is how I use it and how I learned it and I agree with what I learned ;)